# button save data NSUserDefaults doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsuserdefaults

Hello!

I begin with Xcode (and I'm French so my english isn't perfect sorry) and I would need your help please. 
My project is to make an app which would calculate my average in class for each school subject (five). I used the variable `NSUserDefaults` to save my marks but it doesn't work and I don't know why.

This attached my `ViewController.h` for one subject school (the others are pretty the same, only the variable changes)

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface INF231ViewController : UIViewController{

IBOutlet UITextField *INF231CC1;
IBOutlet UITextField *INF231CC2;
IBOutlet UITextField *INF231ET1;
IBOutlet UITextField *INF231ET2;
IBOutlet UILabel *INF231moyenne;}

@property(nonatomic,retain) UITextField *INF231CC1;
@property(nonatomic,retain) UITextField *INF231CC2;
@property(nonatomic,retain) UITextField *INF231ET1;
@property(nonatomic,retain) UITextField *INF231ET2;
@property(nonatomic,retain) UILabel *INF231moyenne;

- (IBAction)INF231save:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)INF231calculer:(id)sender;

@end
```

And this is the ViewController.m :

```
#import "INF231ViewController.h"
@interface INF231ViewController ()
@end

@implementation INF231ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

int INF231noteCC1 = [defaults integerForKey:@"INF231noteCC1"];
int INF231noteCC2 = [defaults integerForKey:@"INF231noteCC2"];
int INF231noteET1 = [defaults integerForKey:@"INF231noteET1"];
int INF231noteET2 = [defaults integerForKey:@"INF231noteET2"];

NSString *INF231noteCC1String = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",INF231noteCC1];
NSString *INF231noteCC2String = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",INF231noteCC2];
NSString *INF231noteET1String = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",INF231noteET1];
NSString *INF231noteET2String = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",INF231noteET2];

INF231CC1.text = INF231noteCC1String;
INF231CC2.text = INF231noteCC2String;
INF231ET1.text = INF231noteET1String;
INF231ET2.text = INF231noteET2String;

[super viewDidLoad];}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];}

- (IBAction)INF231save:(id)sender {
[INF231CC1 resignFirstResponder];
[INF231CC2 resignFirstResponder];
[INF231ET1 resignFirstResponder];
[INF231ET2 resignFirstResponder];

int INF231noteCC1 = [[INF231CC1 text] integerValue];
int INF231noteCC2 = [[INF231CC2 text] integerValue];
int INF231noteET1 = [[INF231ET1 text] integerValue];
int INF231noteET2 = [[INF231ET2 text] integerValue];

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

[defaults setInteger:INF231noteCC1 forKey:@"INF231noteCC1"];
[defaults setInteger:INF231noteCC2 forKey:@"INF231noteCC2"];
[defaults setInteger:INF231noteET1 forKey:@"INF231noteET1"];
[defaults setInteger:INF231noteET2 forKey:@"INF231noteET2"];

[defaults synchronize];

NSLog(@"Data saved");}

@end
```

When I push the button 'save' it is written in the Console "Data saved" but the Keyboard isn't disabled and the data disappeared.

I also put a picture of the `Main.Storyboard` so you can see better [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHbid.png). If you need everything else to figure out where is the problem and to help me solve it, don't hesitate.

I was wondering too if I should use different variable for

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
```

of "*defaults" though I have other data to save in others `ViewController` for my other subject school.


Thanks a lot if you take the time to help me!

Version of Xcode : 7.3.1
Version of iOS : 9.3.3

Comment: what is the output, when you log `INF231noteCC1` to the console?

Comment: I don't know how to log INF231noteCC1 to the console..

Comment: if my answer worked, you don't need to log it.

Comment: I've succeeded to log INF231noteCC1 to the console and when I enter a value it displays 0 (not the value I entered)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this:

```
@implementation INF231ViewController
@synthesize INF231CC1, INF231CC2, INF231ET1, INF231ET2; // add

@end
```

Hope it helps to you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between `int` and `NSInteger`.

`[[INF231CC1 text] integerValue]` returns an `NSInteger`, but you save it in an `int`.

This should work instead:

```
NSInteger INF231noteCC1 = [[INF231CC1 text] integerValue];
```

The same is for `NSUserDefaults`:

`integerForKey` returns an `NSInteger` and not `int`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've changed what you said but it still doesn't work.. any other ideas?